# Move marker in Google map when latitude longitude changes

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

In my application am creating an array list containing latitude and longitude from JSON and adding marker in the map by using the array list but when the lat long changes the marker moves from one position to another but it creates two markers instead of moving, If I give map.clear(), the whole marker getting disable and enabling but I want to remove the old marker how is it possible without using map.clear(),please help

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {

```
        if (mMap == null) { 
            mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap(); 
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

            Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation(); 
            if (mMap != null) {  
                //mMap.clear();
                
                // setUpMap(); 
                mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() { 

                    @Override 
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) { 

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                        final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder(); 
                     mMap.clear();
                        if (marker != null) {
                             marker.remove();
                         }
                        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.size(); i++) { 
                            final LatLng position = new LatLng(Double 
                                    .parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get("Latitude")), 
                                    Double.parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get( 
                                            "Longitude"))); 
                            String ime1 = arraylist1.get(i).get("IME");

                            final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() 
                            .position(position); 
                            //mMap.addMarker(options); 
                            //mMap.addMarker(options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.buspng)).title(ime1));
                            
                              marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.buspng)).title(ime1));

                            //options.title(ime1);
                            builder.include(position); 
                        
                        } 
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0 
                                .getLongitude()); 
                        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
                        // mMap.setOnMapClickListener(null); 
                        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(null); 

                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(9)); 
                    } 
                }); 

            } 
        } 
    } 

    /*  protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException { 
        HttpURLConnection conn = null; 
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(); 
        try { 

            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL); 
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()); 

            int read; 
            char[] buff = new char[1024]; 
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) { 
                json.append(buff, 0, read); 
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e); 
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e); 
        } finally { 
            if (conn != null) { 
                conn.disconnect(); 
            } 
        } 
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 

    } */

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
        String result=""; 
        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            super.onPreExecute(); 
        }

        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            try { 
                arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); 
                String result = ""; 

                json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(SERVICE_URL); 

                try { 
                    //arraylist1.clear(); 

                    jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("SingleIMEs"); 
                    Log.d("Haaaaaaaaaaaa", "" + json); 

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) { 
                        Log.d("H11111111111111111111111111", 
                                "" + jsonarray.length()); 
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                        json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i); 

                        // pubname = json.getString("PubName"); 
                        latitude = json.getDouble("Latitude"); 
                        longitude = json.getDouble("Longitude"); 
                        ime = json.getString("IME");
                        //  map.put("PubName", json.getString("PubName")); 
                        //map.put("PubID", json.getString("PubID")); 
                        map.put("Latitude", json.getString("Latitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLAT",""+json.getString("Latitude") );
                        map.put("Longitude", json.getString("Longitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLONG",""+json.getString("Longitude") );

                        map.put("IME", json.getString("IME"));
                        arraylist1.add(map); 
                    } 

                } catch (JSONException e) { 
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
                    result="Error"; 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            }catch(Exception e){ 
                result="Error"; 
            } 

            return null; 
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) { 

            // mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 

        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        mMapView.onResume(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onPause() { 
        super.onPause(); 
        mMapView.onPause(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() { 
        mMapView.onDestroy(); 
    super.onDestroy(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onLocationUpdated!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("onLocationUpdated!!!","");
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
        setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView);*/

    }
    

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 
    

}
```

Comment: call map.clear() before mMap.addMarker(options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.buspng)).title(ime1));

Comment: @RishadAppat: If I add map.clear() the whole marker is getting disabled  but I want to remove the particular old marker which the lat long changes

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to identify your markers somehow, every marker has to have a uniq id, lets say it's a `String`.

Then you need to store your markers.

```
private HashMap<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();
```

Then before update markers with new data you need to make a copy of previous markers collection to find out which one is newly added and which one is missing:

```
HashMap<String, Marker> oldMarkers = mMarkers;
mMarkers = new HashMap<>();

for (YourMarkerObject m : newMarkers) { // I assume you have collections of your objects here
  String id = m.getId(); // Get an id
  Marker marker = oldMarkers.get(id);
  if (marker == null) { // it means it's the new one
    // Create marker and attach it to the map on the right position
  } else { // it means we already have this marker attached, so just move it
    marker.setPosition(m.getPosition());
    oldMarkers.remove(id); // Remove this one from old markers collection
  }

  mMarkers.put(id, marker);
}

for (Marker oldMarker : oldMarkers.values()) {
  // Detach old markers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to hold onto all the markers you create when you create them since there is no way to get a specific marker from the map once its plotted. Then all you have to do is find the marker from your list and update it.

I use a `HashMap` to store the markers so I can quickly reference them by some key

Comment: tyczj : Can u please post a edited code for my application because I cant able to do with HashMap please post a sample or edit my above code please